# Prevent asp.net core from removing response headers during errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have some middleware that adds two response headers as one of the first thing in the asp.net core pipeline. However when an exception occurs, the default error middleware in asp clears all the headers. This is a problem for both the developer exception pages, and the normal error handling middleware.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening, or at least always guarantee that the headers we want are included?

This is how we set the headers right now:

```cs
    public class LoggerRequestMiddleware : IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            var scope = LogScopeStorage.Scope;

            context.Response.Headers[LoggingConstants.RequestHeaderKey] = scope.RequestId;
            context.Response.Headers[LoggingConstants.SpanHeaderKey] = scope.SpanId;

            await next(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [`HttpResponse.OnStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#do-not-modify-the-status-code-or-headers-after-the-response-body-has-started)  to set the headers before the response headers are flushed to the client.

Comment: @Lightman That does indeed work, thank you!

Comment: @RasmusHansen is this still working for you? On net5.0 here and my headers that I add inside a `Response.OnStarting` are still getting cleared if there is an exception. This is with the DeveloperExceptionPage middleware not being used

Comment: After trying more options, I settled on `app.UseExceptionHandler(error => error.Run(context => Task.CompletedTask))` to get my non-development environments to maintain headers correctly.